# Wordpress - passing a php object to a new page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a custom ordering site built using Wordpress. I've created an object-oriented plugin to store all the order details. (product specs, contact information, various options, etc)  The ordering process spans three pages. What is the best way for me to pass the object from one page to the next that is the most widely browser friendly? JSON encoding? Serialization?  $_SESSION variable? Wordpress does not allow this natively, but I found instructions on how to override this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend storing data in different indexes of `$_SESSION`, so the information will remain persistent across pages.

Because you aren't implementing a feature like search, `$_SESSION` is good choice because users may switch between ordering products and visiting other pages on your site. Additionally, this method does not depend on browser features.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response.  I am struggling with working inside Wordpress.  As a developer I feel like I have my hands tied behind my back because none of my go to strategies work.  I went through the steps to enable $_SESSION vars and am still having trouble with that approach.  Anyone implemented anything similar in Wordpress (multi-page forms)?  I'm getting ready to start searching plugins to see what I can find.

Comment: My name isn't David, but no problem. Check out this link: http://devondev.com/2012/02/03/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/ and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry autibyte!  Not sure what I was looking at there.  Thanks for the link.  I had trouble getting session vars to work at first.  Turns out I had the syntax wrong.